# knockout underscore loop in loop loses observable functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to build table with knockout and underscore.js .
I've  faced with situation, when I need to place one loop in another, like:

```
<tbody >     
  <% _.each(ShippingCharge.Lines(), function(line) { %>
    <tr>  
       <td><input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value : line.ShippingZone.Name"/></td>
       <% _.each(line.Charges(), function(data) { %>
         <td><input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value : data"/></td>
       <% }) %>                     
    </tr>  
  <% }) %>
</tbody>
```

The problem is when `line.Charges()` values are modified, `observableArray` don't updates. You can check it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NW5Vn/132/). Please pay attention, that only nested loop don't updates `observaleArray` , you can change `Zones` column values and see that they change `observaleArray`

Comment: I think I've found something. I had json Array like :  Charges: ["23","43","12"], and when I've changed it to  Charges: [{charge : "3"},{charge : "14"},{charge : "24"}] + `in html <td><input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value : data.charge"/></td>,` these values became observable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the mapping plugin you are struggling with. The mapping plugin can do magic, but sometimes the ViewModel is not correct or to complex for the mapping plugin to handle.

First this remark is important:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

> Key point: An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array, not the state of those objects

If you look at the result of the mapping operation, the property

```
vm.ShippingCharge.Lines()[0].Charges
```

is an observable array.

Your requirment is to be able to change the indivdual Charges (track the state of every single object in the Charges array). So it should be an array of observables, or when the number of values in the array is dynamic, an observable array of observables.

I am not sure if the mapping plugin can do this.

Any how, i think your ViewModel is to complex for the mapping plugin, so leave the magic for what it is, and manual code a view model.

Updated (working) fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/martijn/NW5Vn/145/